# WeakReference - Am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, weak-references

I have a static class, which exposes a event:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    static bool myBool= false;
    public static bool MyBool
    {
        get { return myBool; }
        private set
        {
            myBool= value;

            var handler = MyBoolChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(null, null);
        }
    }

    public static event EventHandler MyBoolChanged;
}
```

And then I am registering to it using this pattern:

```
class AnotherClass
{    
    WeakReference _me;

    public MyMethodInAnotherClass()
    {
        _me = new WeakReference(this);
        MyStaticClass.MyBoolChanged+= 
                (_me.Target as AnotherClass).MyMethodInAnotherClassCallback;    
    }

    private void MyMethodInAnotherClassCallback(some arguments)
    {
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is that `MyStaticClass` will only execute the handler if the instance of `AnotherClass` has not been disposed (and has not deregistered).

Comment: No, you aren't doing it right; you have explicitly given out a reference to yourself by reading `_me.Target`, which is then stored on the event subscription.

Comment: BTW, static events are **deadly** for memory leaks; are you **sure** that is what you want?

Comment: @MarcGravell i keep coming back to this post, just because i cant believe i didnt realize that myself. must have been in a serious brainfart kondition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can see to use this is to forget about an event, and use some kind of list instead; let's say `List<WeakReference>`; you could then have:

```
interface IFoo {
    void Bar(some args);
}
```

with:

```
static class Whatever {
    private static readonly List<WeakReference> items=new List<WeakReference>();
    public static void Add(IFoo foo) {
        if(foo != null) {
            var newRef = new WeakReference(foo);
            lock(items) { items.Add(newRef); }
        }
    }
    public static void DoIt(some args) {
        lock(items) {
           foreach(var item in items) {
              IFoo foo = item.IsAlive ? item.Target as IFoo : null;
              if(foo != null) foo.Bar(some args);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

with additional mechanisms to remove a specific IFoo, and to remove all dead foos left todo.

Then you just need `AnotherClass : IFoo`, with a `Bar()` implementation that applies your callback.

Additional emphasis: static collections (including events) are fairly dangerous; you must have some kind of sweep occasionally to remove empty items, and try to unsubscribe promptly where possible (in `Dispose()`, for example). As an illustration:

```
public static void Remove(IFoo foo) {
    lock (items) { // also remove any dead debris
        items.RemoveAll(x => !x.IsAlive || x.Target == foo || x.Target == null);
    }
}
```